# Can I transfer money to my other user account?

Tags: hackmud

I've got a ton of money on one of my user accounts. I'd like to transfer some of it to my 2nd user account, but when I try to do accts.xfer_gc_to and specify my other username, it says the user doesn't exist.

Is there any way to transfer money to my other user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your second user account is still stuck in the vLAN (tutorial section of the game). You won't be able to transfer GC to your other account until you free it from the vLAN.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out that was the issue. Actually, both accounts were still in the VLAN. But I can definitely confirm that you can't transfer between your accounts until both are out.